# How to display the stream publish dialog with PHP sdk for Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I would like show the confirmation publish dialog before publish to a wall, like that:

[image: http://blog.hackedexistence.com/wp-content/gallery/facebook/publish-to-wall.png]

I have only found how to publish without confirmation, such as:

```
$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'post', $attachment))
```

I am not sure whether it is possible with PHP, the Facebook documentation is not up to date...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using PHP. You just need the facebook dialog to post to your wall in the manner you want. URL will be like:

```
url=https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=<your appid>&redirect_uri=<your redirecting link>&link=<link u are posting>&message=Join+me+at+this+event.&picture=<picture URL you want to show>&caption=Nation+Wide+Broadcast+System&description=This+is+a+test+of+the+Nation+Wide+Broadcast+System.&name=NationWideBarCrawl
```

Just remember that the redirect URI must be same as you set in your facebook app otherwise it will throw an error.

Comment: Thank you. What should I put in redirect_uri=<your redirecting link> ?

Comment: I there also a link to post to a friend wall, including the selection of the friend?

Comment: No, redirect URI is not for posting on facebook app but it is the URL where you will be redirected after you are done with the post. Just put the URL where u want to redirect after you have posted the feed. Also remember the redirect URI domain name must be same as mentioned in the app. Just use URL of the page from which you are using to send the post....

Comment: For more information just visit http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ . It has a very good example